# How can I solve Angular installing problem?

Tags: angular-cli

I keep meeting following errors when I tried to install Angular:

```
C:\Users\geng>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN deprecated ini@1.3.5: Please update to ini >=1.3.6 to avoid a prototype pollution issue
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.2.0: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\geng\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\geng\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\geng\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng' -> 'C:\Users\geng\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd'
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\geng\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\geng\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-09T14_19_26_542Z-debug.log
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: "npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\geng\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly." Did you try this? (Hint: reading error messages usually helps ...)

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! I just re-tried! After I deleted all existing documents, it worked!

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem and l fix it by using these steps:

1- execute the command: `npm cache clean --force`

2- Try to reinstall Angular with: `npm install -g @angular/cli`

This will work fine...